# Index Match when there are multiple matching rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sample data set (below) that has duplicate entries in Column A - I am trying to pull all matching values from Columns B:D when the primary key matches in Column A.

| Primary Key | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 |  |  |
| A |  | 2 |  |
| A |  | 2 | 3 |
| B | 1 |  |  |
| B |  |  | 3 |
| C |  | 2 |  |

Desired Results:

| Primary Key | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| B | 1 |  | 3 |
| C |  | 2 |  |

I have tried a number of iterations of Index(Match), Vlookup, and array formulas - and I'm completely stumped.

Example formula being used: `=index(Data!B:B,match(A2,Data!A:A,0))`

Comment: Is it possible, for example, in Col A that record A might have 2 different values in Column B? (so 4 records of A in your example, 2 of which have values in column B)

Comment: @MarkS. that is a possibility. Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my data set to reflect that.

Comment: would that change your outcome at all? I see it still says 2 on the bottom table, you wouldn't want these summed, correct?

Comment: I would not want it to change the outcome - I would want only the unique values for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want one value per column, you can aggregate the data with `query()` like this:

```
=query( 
  A1:D, 
  "select A, max(B), max(C), max(D) 
   where A is not null 
   group by A", 
  1 
)
```

To add another column, adjust the range reference and add the column in the `select` clause like this:

```
=query( 
  A1:E, 
  "select A, max(B), max(C), max(D), max(E) 
   where A is not null 
   group by A", 
  1 
)
```

To prettify column names, add a `label` clause. See the [query language help page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax).

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D="",,A2:A&"×"&B2:D&"×"&B1:D1)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3 label Col1'Primary Key'"))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked in the sample data set! If I wanted to expand it to, say a 4th column, do I only change the variables in the IF statement or do I need to adjust the query as well?

Comment: @RobertK only the IF statement needs to be changed for 4th column

Comment: Using `query-pivot` with the `split(flatten(if()))` construct seems overly complex for the job, when a simple `query-group by` gives the exact same result.